# pipe send and receive. unpack requires a string argument of length 4

Tags: python, struct, pipe

Understand that this qn has already be asked. But with the answers provided from previous thread, I am still not able to get my program running.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import os
import sys
import time
import struct
path= "pipe"

fifo=open(path,'r')
while True:
    var=fifo.read()
    if var:
      if len(var) == 8:
        print struct.unpack("<l", var)[0]
      print len(var)
```

I want to read from my pipe. I have a c++ program sending struct of 8 bytes to the pipe. If i were to change c++ program to send just a long data type (4 bytes) and i change if len(var) == 8: to if len(var) == 4:, I can get my data correctly. But if i send a struct of 8 bytes (2 long data type), I will get an error.

Will appreciate help greatly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an 8 byte signed long data type, you need to use the 'q' format character, not the 'l' character.

The formatting codes are shown in section 7.3.2.2 of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)

Run this code as a simple example, which sends as either 4 or 8 byte signed long, and checks the length on receipt and uses the appropriate code:

```
import os
import struct

pipein, pipeout = os.pipe()

#txdata = struct.pack("<l", 12345)
txdata = struct.pack("<q", 12345)
print len(txdata)

os.write(pipeout, txdata)

var = os.read(pipein, 1024)
print len(var)
if (len(var) == 4):
    print struct.unpack("<l", var)[0]
if (len(var) == 8):
    print struct.unpack("<q", var)[0]
```